# Visual diff software compatible with svn 1.7 for mac osx

Tags: macos, svn, diff

Does anyone know of any software that can do a visual diff on an svn 1.7 repo (preferably free or free trial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools that can be integrated  with SVN.

Check out this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187064/graphical-diff-for-mac-os-x